# Trying to use surrogate pairs

Tags: java, android, unicode, surrogate-pairs

I am trying to display a playing card using Unicode in Java/Android Studio.  the Unicode for the card is U+1F0A1     which I understand can't be used and must be converted to surrogate pairs.

the code I have entered is

```
    public String getShortName() {
    char spades = 0xD83C/0xDCA1;
    return String.valueOf(spades);
```

however, this doesn't display the card on the emulator.  I have tried numerous variations of the surrogate pairs but nothing happens.  Can anyone help please?

Many thanks

Comment: Use a string literal with unicode escapes: `"\uD83C\uDCA1"`, or simply a string literal with the character: "".

Comment: Where did you find the expression ``0xD83C/0xDCA1``?

Comment: The expression `0xD83C/0xDCA1` is performing integer division, so you are actually setting `char spades = 55356 / 56481;`, which is 0, which is not what you want.  You should use `return "\uD83C\uDCA1;"` or `return "";`, like teppic suggested. Or, you can put the codepoint value into an `int[]` array and use the `String` constructor that takes codepoints as input: `return new String(new int[]{ 0x1F0A1 }, 0, 1);`

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  I have tried to input the surrogate pair as suggested above ("\uD83C\uDCA1") but this does not print anything to the emulator.  The reason I was using the 0xD83C/0xDCA1 is I have successfully implemented unicode in this way.  ```char hearts = 0x2665;
                return String.valueOf(hearts);```